# progress bar implementation using <pe:exporter > in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, progress-bar, primefaces-extensions, data-export

I would like to export data to Excel. Right now I am able to achieve this using `<pe:exporter>`. But when data is huge, it takes a lot of time to export to Excel. I would like to show a progress bar while exporting data to excel. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your xhtml :

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />

<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
    <p:graphicImage name="/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
</p:dialog>
```